# JMeter - user.dir

Tags: jmeter

I want to set Home directory for my 'jmx' files to be open when starting JMeter, using property 'user.dir' from the file: 'user.properties', but without any success. My JMeter's version is 5.5. Please, tell me how to set 'Home' directory for 'jmx' files using configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong configuration file, `user.dir` is a [Java System Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) hence you need to set it in *system.properties* file.

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks so much 'Ivan G' this make sense and works!